# Initialization function of qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state

the IBMQ has a initialize function to provide input to the quantum circuit. I am not  understanding the logic used in the initialization function?
Please give me some link related to some useful paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for: [Arbitrary initialization](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html#Arbitrary-initialization)

Qiskit uses the method proposed in this paper: [Synthesis of Quantum Logic Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176)

---

**Other related papers:**

1. [Quantum-state preparation with universal gate decompositions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5760)
2. [Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0407010.pdf)
3. [Quantum Circuits for Isometries](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06911.pdf)
4. [Constructive Quantum Shannon Decomposition from Cartan Involutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4015)

Comment: Thank you @KAJ226 for sharing these papers.